# HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

Tags: windows-server-2012, asp.net, iis-8

Just installed a new IIS server. We did this after installing .net Framework.

We are getting the following error:

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

---

The website works on domain.com but prompts the above error with www.domain.com or any other subdomain like dev.domain.com . HTML files work on the domain and subdomains. The above error is prompted when .aspx are queried.

Any clues?

---

We did aspnet_regiis and it installed fine.

Some background info:

Windows Server 2012
IIS 8

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. How did you manage to solve this issue ?